# Limiting Spring Controller To Concurrently Handle only few request

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, servlets

In spring controller, there is a huge I/O operation for each request, example loading huge data on memory. For such operations, if server handles all requests at a time, server will finally throw out of memory.
Is there any way in Spring MVC to limit number of concurrent requests (say 5) and block further requests until current 5 requests are processed.

Comment: Is it all the endpoints which uses a lot of data loading in memory or just selective endpoints? If all endpoints, why not employ some caching strategy.

Answer (score 4):

This is normally handled at the web-container level; i.e. in Tomcat or Netty or Glassfish or ... whatever you are using to host your servlets.  You can typically configure the number of request threads that the container runs.

---

I don't think that Spring MVC has built-in support for limiting the number of simultaneous requests.  However, you could possibly implement this with a `Filter`.

(Ugly.  Better to do it at the container level ... IMO.)